# How do i get result based on occurence in array for a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

hi i have this test data i want to get result something like this

```
na ===> not available

error ===> error

ok  ===> ok

arr1 = ['na','na','ok','ok','na']  => na 

arr2 = ['ok','ok','ok','ok','error'] => error

arr2 = ['ok','ok','ok','ok','ok'] => ok
```

Comment: The question not clear enough.
how bout
arr3 = ['ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'na', 'ok', 'ok'] ?
is it gonna be na?

Comment: `arr1 = ['na','na','ok','ok','na']`  => na  (**`na` is result**)

Comment: and how about ['ok','na','error'] ?

Comment: Are you trying to get the last element of the array?

Comment: 5 element all the times

Comment: @Eddie, which ever has more occurence

Comment: Your second example has more `ok` than `error`

Comment: arr1 = ['ok','ok','ok','na','ok'] -> how bout this? Looks like you only take the last element.

Comment: If the logic is  get has more occurrences. What if there is an equal like `['na','na','ok','ok','error']`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you want as result an `element` which has more occurrences in an `array`, this may helps:

```js
var arr = ['na','na','ok'];

console.log(getMoreOccurencesElement(arr));

arr.push('ops');
arr.push('ops');
arr.push('ops');

console.log(getMoreOccurencesElement(arr));

function getMoreOccurencesElement(arr) {
return arr
  .reduce((acc, ele) => {
    var prev = acc.find(x => x.value == ele);
    if(prev) {
      prev.counter = prev.counter + 1;
      return acc;
    }
    return acc.concat({value: ele, counter: 1})
  }, [])
  .sort((a, b) => b.counter - a.counter)[0].value;
}
```

Comment: does the above solution work for any dynamically added values to the `Array`?

Comment: @EaB you can refact it into a function then call it anytime. i've just edited adding this case, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use an elseif or a switch to determine if there is either an "na" or an "error" in the array.

Logic is based on the first instance of either an "na" or an "error" to set the array as that type. Not sure if the logic should be to find all the instances and then set the status based on the total number / greeatest number of either na / error.

EDIT - I have added a switch statement option to demonstrate that path - note that the trigger for the switch is the result of hte indexOf() expression rather than the presence of a string.

```js
arr1 = ['na','na','ok','ok','na'];
arr2 = ['ok','ok','ok','ok','error'];
arr3 = ['ok','ok','ok','ok','ok'];

function checkArray(arr) {
 if ( arr.indexOf('na') !== -1 ) {
  return "na";
 } else if(arr.indexOf('error') !== -1) {
    return "error";
 } else {
   return "ok";
 }
}


 console.log("Using an elseif block")
 console.log(checkArray(arr1)); // gives 'na'
 console.log(checkArray(arr2)); // gives 'error'
 console.log(checkArray(arr3)); // gives 'ok'
 
 

 
 function checkArray2(arr) {
  switch(true) {
    case  arr.indexOf('na') !== -1:
        return "na"
        break;
    case  arr.indexOf('error') !== -1:
        return "error"
        break;
    default:
        return "ok"
  }
}

 console.log(" ")
 console.log("Using a switch statement")
 console.log(checkArray2(arr1)); // gives 'na'
 console.log(checkArray2(arr2)); // gives 'error'
 console.log(checkArray2(arr3)); // gives 'ok'
```

Comment: the result is coorect, but can this solution accomodate a new value added dynamically to a `array`.  if you can provide example please

Comment: Hi - this solution can adapt to any number of elements in the array - since you pass the array into it as an argument when calling it - so you would dynamically add the elements to the array and then call the function with the new array in it. Note that I edited the answer to include a switch statement for diversity of options.

Answer (score 0):

```js
arr1 = ['na', 'na', 'ok', 'ok', 'na'];
arr2 = ['ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'error'];
arr3 = ['ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok', 'ok'];

function count(arr) {
  var na_count = arr.filter(function(a) {return a === 'na';}).length;
  var error_count = arr.filter(function(a) {return a === 'error';}).length;
  var ok_count = arr.filter(function(a) {return a === 'ok';  }).length;
  var length = arr.length
  if (length === ok_count) {
    return 'ok';
  }else if (na_count > error_count) {
    return 'na';
  }else {
    return 'error';
  }

}
console.log('using arr1', count(arr1))
console.log('using arr2', count(arr2))
console.log('using arr3', count(arr3))
```